# Issues with jar exporter tool

Tags: java, jar, compilation, java-compiler-api, javacompiler

I am attempting to write a Java project, which will compile any Java project and export a *.jar file. The program expects 3 runtime arguments, which I am specifying as:

```
C:\dev\Kronos\Kronos
vendor
src\com\starworks\kronos
```

Here is my code so far:

```
public class GenJar {
    
    private static String PROJECT_DIR;
    private static String DEPENDENCIES_DIR;
    private static String SRC_DIR;

    private static final List<String> s_classpath = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static final List<String> s_sourceFiles = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PROJECT_DIR = args[0];
        DEPENDENCIES_DIR = PROJECT_DIR + File.separator + args[1];
        SRC_DIR = PROJECT_DIR + File.separator + args[2];

        File dependenciesDir = new File(DEPENDENCIES_DIR);
        for (File file : dependenciesDir.listFiles()) {
            if (!file.getName().endsWith(".jar") || (file.getName().contains("sources") || file.getName().contains("javadoc"))) {
                continue;
            }
            s_classpath.add(file.getPath());
            System.out.println("Added dependency: " + file.getPath());
        }
        
        File srcDir = new File(SRC_DIR);
        for (File file : srcDir.listFiles()) {
            addSourceFiles(file);
        }

        int success = compile();
        if (success != 0) {
            System.err.println("Compilation failed!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.out.println("Compilation successful!");
        
        Manifest manifest = new Manifest();
        manifest.getMainAttributes().put(Attributes.Name.MANIFEST_VERSION, "1.0");
        manifest.getMainAttributes().put(Attributes.Name.CLASS_PATH, String.join(";", s_classpath));
        
        exportJar();
    }

    private static int compile() {
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        return compiler.run(null, null, null, "-d", PROJECT_DIR + File.separator + "bin", "-cp", String.join(File.pathSeparator, s_classpath), String.join(" ", s_sourceFiles));
    }
    
    private static void exportJar() {
    }

    private static void addSourceFiles(File file) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = file.listFiles();
            if (files != null) {
                for (File f : files) {
                    addSourceFiles(f);
                }
            }
        } else {
            s_sourceFiles.add(file.getPath());
            System.out.println("Added source file: " + file.getPath());
        }
    }
}
```

When running the program, this error occurs:

(%fn[x]% stands for file name, since they are quite long; filename e.g. C:\dev\Kronos\Kronos\src\com\starworks\kronos\Configuration.java)

```
error: Invalid filename: %fn[0]% %fn[1]% %fn[2]% .. %fn[N]%
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
Compilation failed!
```

I believe the issue boils down to not knowing how to properly target multiple source files for compilation, but I am not sure what the issue is precisely. Any assistance would be apricated.

I wrote an application which targets the directory of a Java project, to then be exported as a *.jar file. I expected the code to compile the source directory of a java project, but the files aren't being targeted in the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#CBHHCGFB suggests to me you want to ; separate the files in the -cp option to the compiler. It looks like you're using spaces and you may want to try semi colons